# Visual studio 2013 how to connect two classes

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am making a text editor however the code is getting pretty big and I was trying to find a way to separate my code into multiple files but being able to use functions from the file.

Hint:
Something like as we say in PHP  " require 'something.php' "

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `partial` keyword in C# or `Partial` in VB.NET.
This keyword allows to split a big class contained in a single file and reposition part of the code in another file.

Example in C#

In file `EmployeeModel.cs`

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    ..... other properties
    ..... or methods

}
```

in file `EmployeesActions.cs`

```
// This file contains all the `economics` related to an employee
public partial class Employee
{
    public decimal CalculateSalary(int month, int year)
    {
        ......
    }
}
```

In this way you could use an instance of an Employee from a third class (an UI interface for example) without any problem caused by the split in two different file of the Employee class

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
emp.Name = "Steve";

decimal wage = emp.CalculateSalary(10, 2013);
```

Comment: I am using VB.NET. I am trying to call specific things such as textbox.clear() from the main form however I am getting an error on it.

Comment: "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference."

Comment: I think you need to update your question showing the code that give the error